# How to display First few entries in view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

i have uploaded eight products with images in database using code first entity framework and all are displaying on index view, i want to show only first four products in a row and next four in second page of gallery so how can i do that..?? this is my code.. I am trying to use @for loop for it and tells it first four but i doesn't works.

```
public class Product    
{    
    [Key]    
    public int ProductId { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name ="Name: ")]    
    public string Name { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name ="Description: ")]     
    public string Description { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name = "Price: ")]    
    public decimal Price { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name ="Discount: ")]     
    public double Discount { get; set; }    
    [Display(Name ="Quantity: ")]    
    public int Quantity { get; set; }    
    public int ImageSize { get; set; }    
    public string FileName { get; set; }    
    public byte[] ImageData { get; set;}    
    [NotMapped]    
    [Required]     
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }    
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: post the code for your loop that you have currently tried. All you have currently posted is a class definition.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use the `Skip()` and `Take()` methods. 
Skip will skip the number of records you specify and Take will take the next number of records you specify. You need to keep track of the number of records already displayed.

```
int AlreadyDisplayed = 0;
int NumberToDisplay = 4;

var Selections = context.Stuff
                  .Select()
                  .Skip(AlreadyDisplayed)
                  .Take(NumberToDisplay)
                  .ToList();

AlreadyDisplayed += NumberToDisplay;
```

Comment: we can use in in view?

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {
            List<Product> all = new List<Product>();
            using (BootstrapDBContext db = new BootstrapDBContext())
            {
                all = db.Product.ToList();
            }
            return View(all);
        }

Comment: You've to query from your controller and use it on your view. To do that, you can use ViewBag for example.